# Amazon's Database Migration Service (DMS) - Exact meaning of "Partially supported datatypes"

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, amazon-rds

I have several columns in my db that are float8, I'm looking to do a direct **postgres10 to postgres10 migration** between two RDS instances.

Upon doing the Assessment for the task, it states there are several occurrences of "Partially Supported Datatypes":

[image: AWSPartially supported datatypes]

Looks like it found 29 occurrences of float8's mainly due to geo coordinate values stored in the db:

[image: Partially supported datatypes]

The source and target were created identically regarding Roles/Grants/DB Engine/Parameter groups/etc.

[I found this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migration-validation-part-1-introducing-migration-assessment-in-aws-database-migration-service/) that explains the following:

```
Partially supported
Data types that AWS DMS supports, but when it tries to migrate them, the target data type mapping might not match the source. For example, when you move from PostgreSQL to Oracle, the TEXT data type is mapped as NCLOB on the target and not CLOB or BLOB.
Data types that AWS DMS can migrate, but with partial success. For example, when you move from PostgreSQL to PostgreSQL, JSONB migration works fine if the data in this column is fewer than 255 characters.
```

This doesn't really make sense, the source and target are identical engines. Is there any way to get more details on what the issue is? It should be a direct postgres10 -> postgres10 migration task.

Comment: A couple of years ago I found DMS didn't transfer things like indexes, autoincrement values, etc, for MySQL. Suggest you consider a standard export / import unless you have a specific need for DMS.

Comment: That's a shame, seems like a very useful tool on paper. In practice it seems to be too much trouble